# Problem installing haskell profiling libraries with cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I have a cabal project and I'm trying to compile it with profiling turned on. I'm following the [instructions here](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html) but `cabal build` fails with the following error:

```
app/WordMap.hs:5:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Data.HashMap.Strict’
    Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘unordered-containers-0.2.19.1’?
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
5 | import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HashMap
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The only change I made to cause this was to add the `-prof` and `-fprof-auto` to the `ghc-options` in the .cabal file. It compiles fine without those options.

I'm using GHC version 9.2.4 and cabal version 3.6.2.0.

I've tried running `cabal install unordered-containers --enable-profiling --lib --reinstall` (and various derivatives to that) but it doesn't seem to work. The command completes fine but doesn't change the output of `cabal build`.

I've also tried rm'ing the package from the cabal store, and then installing the package again with profiling. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way forward.
I needed to remove the `-prof` and `-fprof-auto` from the .cabal ghc-options, and then just run `cabal v2-run <project> --enable-profiling -- +RTS -p`.

More info [in the cabal docs](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/nix-local-build.html?highlight=profile#how-can-i-profile-my-library-application).